# Exim log message that refers to issue beyond our control

Tags: exim, centos7

I am noticing  in my mail queue, the following message, many of them, for the same mail recipient domains. (hotmail and xtra.co.nz being but two of MANY)

```
check_mail_permissions could not determine the sender domain
[routed_domain=xtra.co.nz message_exim_id=1ZXvOP-00006m-IR
 sender_host_address=197.221.224.46 recipients_count=1]
```

The ip address listed in this message is a generic IP for our national telecomms providers ADSL network in our town. Users all show this IP when their public IP is queried, the ADSL network runs on a private IP subnet, natted by the ISP's edge routers.

I am at a loss as to what we can do to move the mail along, as it is piling up on our server queue.

Using Exim on Centos 7.

Answer (score 1):

You SHOULD not receive messages from hosts that have no valid reverse DNS record. All hosts from dynamycally assigned provider's networks should use provider's relay for submission. And providers should block any direct traffic on the port 25. 99.99% of directly submitted messages are spam so you can drop them with no doubts.